# Putting "widgets" on Mac desktop

Tags: macos, dashboard, widgets

Is there any software to put certain "widgets" on the desktop, such as notes or a clock? I would like to have apps permanently affixed there, rather than being open as separate apps or hovering over other windows.

Answer (score 6):

In some versions of Mac OS X it is possible to [detach widgets from the Dashboard](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/widgetondesktop.htm) and leave them on the desktop.

### Enable Dashboard Development Mode

1. Launch **Utilities** > **Terminal.app**
2. Issue the command `defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES`
3. Issue the command `killall Dock`
4. Quit **Terminal.app**
5. Display the Dashboard; using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key
6. Click and hold on a widget
7. Hide the Dashboard; using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key
8. In development mode, the widget remains visible and can now be positioned on the Desktop

These steps were originally for Mac OS X 10.4 but this technique is [reported to still work](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4291139) with 10.8, Mountain Lion.

Comment: Doesn't Seem to be working in Mavericks. Just saying because the OP tagged `Mavericks`.

Comment: I am also unable to recreate this on OS X 10.9.2; Apple appears to have removed the behaviour.

Comment: Works in Mavericks. OS X 10.10.3. However, they still float above all other windows.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to go to System Prefrences>Mission Control and uncheck Show Dashboard as a Space...
This still works, killall Dock after moving widgets to desktop

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called the Dashboard that houses widgets. Below is a screenshot of the app icon, and another screenshot of my Dashboard.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question…

Comment: works. then click the Plus sign at the bottom to add widgets..